# ScrollablePane - Scroll to Top

Tags: office-ui-fabric

When using the office ui fabric ScrollablePane - is there a way to scroll back to the top of the list when using a DetailsList?

I've tried binding to the initialScrollPosition props, but it doesn't work like a controlled component.